# Windows Automaton - InvokePattern blocking execution until everything has completed

Tags: automation, ui-automation, automationelement

I have experienced this behavior in my automation application: when I "click" a button by calling the `InvokePattern.Invoke()` method everything stops until the handler of the click event inside the automated application finishes.

While this can make some thing simple (for example I don't have to write tons of code to wait for a dialog with progress bar to disappear, because I simply get the control back when everything is done), but I can't do anything else. It even blocks the access to the Automation API in another thread where it continues after the click handler is done.

This causes problems when click handler in the automated application opens a modal dialog, then I can't do anything, the access to the application through automation API is blocked until the dialog is manually closed.

Has anybody solved this somehow and can help me?

Thanks,
Karel

PS: Reference [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClient/System/Windows/Automation/InvokePattern.cs,82) is saying this:

```
Request that the control initiate its action.
/// Should return immediately without blocking.
/// There is no way to determine what happened, when it happend, or whether
/// anything happened at all
public void Invoke() { ... }
```

**Edit:** It works perfectly when automating Windows notepad application which is not a .NET application. And it does **not** work for a [Notepad clone](https://github.com/luisperezphd/NotepadClone) (C# WinForms aplication).